# Looping through a directory in PHP?

Tags: php, file, loops

I am trying to print print this out in the html

```
 <a id='riverwalk' style='display:none;' href='images/riverwalk/1.jpg' rel='prettyPhoto[riverwalk]'></a>
<a style='display:none;' href='images/riverwalk/2.jpg' rel='prettyPhoto[riverwalk]'></a>
<a style='display:none;' href='images/riverwalk/3.jpg' rel='prettyPhoto[riverwalk]'></a>
<a style='display:none;' href='images/riverwalk/4.jpg' rel='prettyPhoto[riverwalk]'></a>
```

But i want to do it pro grammatically and this is my code..but just not doing anything at all

```
$counter = 0;
$directory = "images/riverwalk"
$dir = opendir ("images/riverwalk");
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
        if ($counter == 0) {
            echo "<a id='riverwalk' style='display:none;' href='images/riverwalk/$file' rel='prettyPhoto[riverwalk]'></a>";
        $counter++;
        }else{
         echo "<a style='display:none;' href='images/riverwalk/$file' rel='prettyPhoto[riverwalk]'></a>";
    $counter++;
}
}
```

does anything look off to anyone...i cant view the errors because i cant turn php errors on...any ideas

FIX: the issue was the a semicolon missing on the second line

Comment: You can't even turn errors on at runtime with `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` ?

Comment: Are you sure that `$dir !== false`?

Comment: Did you check if the opendir() call succeeded? It returns false if it can't open the directory for whatever reason.

Comment: As for guessing: this usually happens when the relative path is wrong. Try `print_r(scandir("images/riverwalk"))` instead. And for a crude way to enable error display `set_error_handler("var_dump")`

Comment: There is one problem still the . and .. file are causing issues....

Comment: Can't you just jump over them with an `if(...) { continue; }`?

Comment: See my code in the answer below, should handle it for you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at scandir() - it's much easier to write and debug..

```
$counter = 0;
$dirf    = 'images/riverwalk';
$dir = scandir($dirf);
foreach($dir as $file) {
   if(($file!='..') && ($file!='.')) {
      if($counter==0)
           echo "<a id='riverwalk' style='display:none;' href='images/riverwalk/$file' rel='prettyPhoto[riverwalk]'></a>";
      else
           echo "<a style='display:none;' href='images/riverwalk/$file' rel='prettyPhoto[riverwalk]'></a>";
      $counter++;
   }
}
```

If that doesn't work use is_dir() to check you're pointing at the correct directory..

Comment: This isn't going to fix anything.

Comment: I beg to differ - it fixes the original problem, is more readable and handles the problem of the .. and ., something the OP has specified.

Comment: Let me put it another way: using `scandir` instead of `opendir` isn't going to fix anything.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I don't go too far by saying: It actually does work, but you can't see anything because your `<a>`'s are empty. Try it with

```
    if ($counter == 0) {
        echo "<a id='riverwalk' style='display:none;' href='images/riverwalk/$file' rel='prettyPhoto[riverwalk]'> blib </a>";
    $counter++;
    }else{
     echo "<a style='display:none;' href='images/riverwalk/$file' rel='prettyPhoto[riverwalk]'> blub </a>";
```

(added 'blib' and 'blub')

*If you did think of this (in that case please provide html source code in your question), tell me in a comment and I'll delete this answer.*

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you missed semicolon (**;**) in line 2 of your PHP code... Try to add ; at the and of line. This code works fine!

consider this line:

```
$directory = "images/riverwalk"
```

Answer (score 0):

$dir = './';
open_dir($dir);

function open_dir($dir = null) {
    global $htaccesscount;

```
if (!empty($dir) && is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                $filetype = filetype($dir . $file);

                switch ($filetype) {
                    case 'dir'          :

                        break;
                    case 'file'         :

                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

}